# Why the vba code is not matching the sheet name when the names exactly line up?

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

[image: Name of the summary sheet]

[image: Picture of the code]

[image: error line]

This code is supposed to pull data from all worksheets and input to the pre-created table in the summary sheet.

I'm getting an error that says the subscript is not recognized on the attached line. It's not recognizing the sheet name. I am not sure why. Thank you

Comment: Because the worksheet "Summary" is in the other workbook, not in ThisWorkbook?

Comment: try using the sheet codename: `Set summarySheet = Summary`

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome Why 3? 10 would be a better guess (but it is still a guess). Maybe it is safer to run `?Len(Summary.Name)` and `Summary.Name="Summary"`.

Comment: Run `?len(sheets(Sheets.Count).name)` in vba immediate window to check how many characters in the summary sheet name. If the result was larger than 7, it means there are non-printable chars. Reset it with sheets(..).name="Summary".

Comment: Finally you don't even need to set a variable at all as you could use `Summary` as this is the code name of the sheet: `set tbl = Summary.ListObjects(1)`. Moreover: using the code name makes the code independant from the sheets name visible to the end user ...

Comment: It looks like since the macro was in my personal workbook instead of the locations where the sheets were it wasn't working... Thank you GSerg, as you lead me in the right direction :)